# how to modify touch events for a custom app-ios button

Tags: css, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm trying add hover, active state to custom back button. custom data-theme is "app-ios" Here is the

`

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
    <div data-theme="c" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Header
        </h3>
        <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-theme="app-ios">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div
</div>
```

`
CSS

```
 /* button background and borders color */
a[data-theme="app-ios"] {
    border: none;
    }
    a[data-theme="app-ios"] .ui-btn-corner-all {
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        background: #ba2669; /* Old browsers */
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.25), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
        overflow: visible;
        padding-left: 8px !important;
        padding-right: 8px !important;
        }
/* shadows and label color */
/* button background and borders color */
a[data-theme="app-ios"] {
    border: none;
    }
    a[data-theme="app-ios"] .ui-btn-corner-all {
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        background: #ba2669;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.25), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
        overflow: visible;
        padding-left: 8px !important;
        padding-right: 8px !important;
        }
/* shadows and label color */
a[data-theme="app-ios"].ui-shadow,
a[data-theme="app-ios"] {
    box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    background-clip: none; -webkit-background-clip: none; -moz-background-clip: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px!important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
    width: 51px;
    }
/* make room for the point */
a[data-theme="app-ios"].ui-btn-left {
    left: 14px;
    }
    a[data-theme="app-ios"].ui-btn-left .ui-btn-corner-all {
        padding-left: 5px !important;
        }
/* position the DIV that contains the point */
a[data-theme="app-ios"] .ios-tip {
    float: left;
    left: -10px;
    top: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.7, 1.0);
    }
/* apply gradient */
a[data-theme="app-ios"] .ios-tip span {
    display: block;
    width: 19px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    /* the gradient color mus be slightly different since the point is within the body of the button */
    background: #ba2669; /* Old browsers */
    border-radius: 1px; -webkit-border-radius: 1px; -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    /*box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.25); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.25); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.25);*/
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(.9, .9);
    }
```

Comment: how does one hover with a mobile app? would this be a touch event?

Comment: Yeah, its a touch event. when tapped I want to have a diff. color